# I want to open new cmd prompt and insert arguments from a cmd prompt

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I tried Start cmd to open new cmd prompt but i am not able to give command line arguments in new cmd ..

I tried with following

```
system("start cmd") >> "system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
```

not working

```
system(start system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig"));
```

not working

Comment: Which platform/language you want to do this in?

Comment: in C language..actually want to implement in minifilter driver...

Answer (score 2):

As said by Dipak D Desai, you can simply use

```
system("cmd /c start C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
```

But if you do that in a non console application, here is what will happen :

- Windows will create a new cmd windows
- it will execute `ipconfig` in that window
- it will close the window as soon as the program `ipconfig` has ended.

If you want the window to stay open after the end of the command, you can use :

```
system("cmd /c start cmd /k C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
```

The first `cmd /c` allows to pass the command `start` that is an internal command. The second `cmd /c` (or `cmd /k`) starts a new shell (`cmd.exe`) but ask it not to close after executing first command, but instead to open a command loop.

In fact, the first `cmd /c` is not necessary, since it is implied by the `system` call. So it should be omitted from the command even if is is harmless (thanks to @eryksun for noticing)

Answer (score 1):

Launch a separate CMD Windows, you need to call cmd.exe:

```
system("cmd.exe /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
```

Comment: I tried with: system("start cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
but my screen is not holding its getting closed

Comment: Thank you i got the outout.

Comment: Good.. if you  get solution using above accept answer. it would help some one who having same issue with same..